# How to order by "Month" using a column that has "Date format" in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a session name and session date, ex:

```
Name: Football game, date: 2020-05-31.
```

Is there a way to display these results in a group by date as in months?? ex:

Date X

1  (month 1) ...

2  (month 2)  ...

...

```
SELECT Date(?) , count(*) nb from Session group by Date(?)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT month(Date) , count(*) nb from Session group by month(Date);
```

Comment: @mohamad . . . Aggregating by the month and not including the year is usually an error -- although it might be what you want in this particular case (your question is not clear).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to show results in a pie chart of how many people attended in this particular month, i linked this query with another table and it worked, it would show like 37% number of attendees in month "3", it worked without error, should i include year? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by month, you can use date functions:

```
select year(date), month(date), count(*)
from t
group by year(date), month(date);
```